# Invisible undefined TextViews in TableLayout

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-layout

I am pretty new to android, so there might be something I am missing.
I have defined simple android layout with few buttons like this.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_column="1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_column="2" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_column="3" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_column="4" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_column="5" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But in designer I can see multiple textViews I did not define. I can even set text to it.

It looks like this. 
[image]

They are not there in run time, but I can select and edit them in design time. Its really annoying. Can anybody please explain?

Comment: What IDE is this issue happening in

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi Visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"/>
    <ImageButton
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button5"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I hope this will resolve your problem. Thanks...

Comment: What exactly did you change and how is it supposed to resolve the issue?

Comment: I can see, there is an extra child of `TableRow` under `TableLayout`.

Comment: Viktor....First tell me this resolved your issue or not....then i can explain it.